# How to create a user with field collections programmatically?

Tags: 7, users, entities

This is what I use to create the user:

```
    $new_user = array(
        'name' => $form_state['values']['email'],
        'status' => 1,
        'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
        'roles' => array(),
    );

   user_save('', $new_user);
```

Now I want to add values to the field collection items. 
I have a field collection called `field_personal_details` and a field collection item called `field_firstname`, but I have no idea how to access it. Can someone help me get started?

Comment: finally, do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think following code should give you an idea.

```
    //Create a field collection entity
    $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_personal_details'));
    $field_collection_item->field_firstname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "Yassin Tahtah";        
    //$field_collection_item->field_firstname['und'][0]['value'] = "Yassin Tahtah";
    $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('user', $user);
    // Save the entity.
    $field_collection_item->save(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see this example:

```
$new_user = array(
    'name' => $form_state['values']['email'],
    'status' => 1,
    'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    'roles' => array(),
);

 //making the field collection
 $values = array();
 $values['field_name'] = 'field_personal_details';
 $values['field_firstname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'Yassin';

 //saving the collection
 $entity = entity_create('field_collection_item', $values);
 $entity->setHostEntity('user', $user);
 $entity->save();    

 //saving the user
 user_save('', $new_user);
```